# Wordpress Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a wordpress site : There is a problem with the pagination.. When I click on 2'nd page it shows up the first one(index page). The other pages are working. Can you help me?
I looked up for errors in the loop but i didn't found anything!

this my index.php code

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
    <?php if(get_option('freshlife_featured_content_enable') == 'on') { ?>
        <div id="featured-content">
            <div class="heading">
                <span class="heading-text"><?php _e('Featured Articles', 'themejunkie'); ?></span>
            </div> <!-- end .heading -->
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $counter = 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'showposts' => get_option('freshlife_featured_post_num'),
                        'tag' => get_option('freshlife_featured_post_tags')         
                    ) );    
                    if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                ?>
                    <li class="featured-<?php echo $counter; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumb', array('class' => 'entry-thumb')); ?></a><span class="entry-date"><abbr title="<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>"><?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . __(' ago', 'themejunkie'); ?></abbr></span><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
                <?php $counter++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end #featured-content -->
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="heading">
        <span class="heading-text"><?php _e('All Stories', 'themejunkie'); ?></span>
    </div> <!-- end .heading -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/templates/loop.php'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); else { ?>
        <div class="pagination">
            <div class="left"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries', 'themejunkie')) ?></div>
            <div class="right"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older Entries', 'themejunkie')) ?></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div> <!-- end .pagination -->  
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- end #content -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without looking at the WP_Query generated by the requests.

But I do see something that might be causing problems, query_posts alters the main query, that could be messing with the pagination.

Try to use get_posts instead query_posts, so the main loop is not affected.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755)